# Create IP address for load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I  need to create an IP address for my load balancer, so that I can use it for an A record in my DNS entry.

I can't see this option anywhere...is this possible and if so, how would I go about creating an IP address for my existing load balance

Comment: it's a very new feature https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers, but may I ask why you need to create a A record instead of CNAME or better an alias

Comment: So the reason I need it (or something like it) is because I need my domain to point to my load balancer...I was able to do this with the CNAME/www entry, but the non-www version of the domain is what I still need to point to the same load balancer....and since the A record requires me to input an IP address, I'm unable to do so.. So now I am stuck with only www.mywebsite.com pointing correctly to my load balancer, and mywebsite.com NOT doing the same thing....I am open to any solutions so long as I can get mywebsite.com to point to my load balancer some how.

Comment: you can have as many CNAMES as you want pointing to the single (E|A)LB

Comment: I put "www" in the host field for CNAME, and it pointed to www.mywebsite.com....what do I put instead of "www" to make the CNAME point to mywebsite.com? That's where I'm stuck

Comment: Try it with a blank instead of `www`

Comment: Tried that - Godaddy made that field required, can't leave it blank

Comment: domain.com is the zone apex. Not all DNS servers support 'CNAME" style records for the apex. Route 53 does via A-ALIAS for tor the apex. AWS NLB does support static IP addresses for each zone. This means that you can create an A record with more than one IP address for the apex - one IP for each NLB AZ. However, keep things simple, move your DNS servers to a provider that has the support that you need. Route 53 is a very good product and is basically free (ALIAS records are free, CNAMES are charged for).

Comment: In regards to leaving the field blank try @. Some DNS servers use the at sign instead of a blank field.

Comment: Tried the * too, they treat it as a wildcard instead...it's driving me crazy...I just want mydomain.com (without the www) to point to this load balancer URL but they make it really hard at Godaddy

Comment: I meant @ as in "at sign" - just switch DNS servers and forgo the headaches.